# How i can display HTML code in xamarin app

Tags: c#, html, xamarin

What is the best way to display local HTML code directly into my page.xaml.cs file? I want to write the html code directly into .cs file. thanks

I will use this in my page.xaml.cs

```
var browser = new WebView();
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
  <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
  <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
  </body></html>";
browser.Source = htmlSource;
```

but in xaml file how I can display this html and put it in a stack layout for example?

Comment: But a .cs file is just a textfile that the compiler converts into a class of a program. So the only thing you can do is using a Multi Line comment

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn i want to display the HTML code in page.xaml

Comment: @MassimoAusiello Use a WebView : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn hi updated my answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using WebView to display local page html in my crossplatform xamarin app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874137/using-webview-to-display-local-page-html-in-my-crossplatform-xamarin-app)

Answer (score 0):

You need HtmlLabel

In Shared project:

```
   public class HtmlLabel : Label
    {

    }
```

droid:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HtmlLabel), typeof(HtmlLabelRenderer))]
namespace MedicinalPlants.Droid
{
    public class HtmlLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement is HtmlLabel element)
                Control.SetText(Html.FromHtml(element.Text), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
        }
    }
}
```

ios:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HtmlLabel), typeof(HtmlLabelRenderer))]
namespace XamarinForms.iOS.CustomRenderer
{
    public class HtmlLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement is HtmlLabel element)
            {
                var nsAttr = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes
                {
                    DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML
                };
                var html = NSData.FromString(element.Text, NSStringEncoding.Unicode);
                var nsError = new NSError();
                Control.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(html, nsAttr, ref nsError);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

using:

```
HtmlLabel htmlLabel = new HtmlLabel();
htmlLabel.Text = "<p>Bilimsel adı : Salvia officinalis</p>";
```