# Using WebView to display local page html in my crossplatform xamarin app

Tags: c#, html, xaml, xamarin, webview

i'm new in developing app with xamarin. I'm developing my first crossplatform app using xamarin forms.  If you can give me the simpliest solution for my problem with examples.

i have a MainPage.xaml with some stacklayout. in one of this stacklayout i want to display a local page.html using a Webview (i think).

thanks you

**my page xaml is this**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App1.info"
             Title="WebView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <WebView x:Name="webview" Source="{Binding mySource}"  />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**my page.xaml.cs is this**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App1
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class info : ContentPage


    {
        public HtmlWebViewSource mySource { get; set; }
        public info()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;

            mySource = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                Html = @"<html><body>
  <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
  <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
  </body></html>"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Xamarin Docs contain full samples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows

Comment: Download the WebView, then put on the form, set the 'Source' property.

Comment: @PoulBak can give me an example?

Comment: @SushiHangover i tried it and it works but the example works only with mainpage.cs that have a tabbed page with 4 page.cs. i want to work also with xaml page because i need to display the webview only in one stacklayout. the example instead show the html code in all of the page.

Answer (score 0):

#### in xaml

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

   <WebView x:Name="webview" Source="{Binding mySource}"  />

</StackLayout>
```

#### in code behind or ViewModel

```
public HtmlWebViewSource mySource { get; set; } 

public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();  
       
   webview.Source = "@"<html><body>
  <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
  <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
  </body></html>";";
}
```

Or you can use data binding(MVVM) .

Comment: Share your sample .

Comment: Try to set the value directly first to check if the issue still exists .

Comment: I dont understand what i will do

Comment: webview.Source = "@"<html><body>
  <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
  <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
  </body></html>";

Comment: really sorry but i don't understand. if you can modify my page so in this way i can understand. sorry for that and for the time